# fetching values from core data always returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im parsing a json and adding those values as a record to core data. I have to save those datas and add them up to db using core data. im using the following code to do so,

```
for (NSDictionary *response in details) {
    NSString *invoiceNo = [response valueForKey:@"invoice_no"];
    NSString *shipmentNumber = [response valueForKey:@"shipment_no"];
    NSString *invoiceDate = [response valueForKey:@"invoice_date"];
    NSString *proformaInvoiceNumber = [response valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
    NSString *proformaInvoiceDate = [response valueForKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
    NSString *plannedShipmentDates = [response valueForKey:@"planned_shipment_dates"];
    NSString *pointOfContact =[[response objectForKey:@"point_of_contact"] valueForKey:@"empid"];
    NSString *pendingStatus = [response valueForKey:@"status"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if (self.pendingShipmentDAO) {
        // Update existing device
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pointOfContact forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"empid"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"products"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"quantity"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"rate"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"amount"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"product_image"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
    } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pointOfContact forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"empid"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"products"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"quantity"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"rate"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"amount"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"product_image"];
        [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
    }
    //
}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (result.count > 0) {
    NSManagedObject *pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:0];
    // NSLog(@"1 - %@", pending);

    NSLog(@"statsus %@ %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"], [pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);

    //  NSLog(@"2 - %@", pending);
}
```

The problem is the `NSLog(@"statsus %@ %@", [pending valueForKey:@"status"], [pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]);`
 always returns null. Why is that so?

Comment: What is `pendingShipmentDAO`?

Comment: But what is the relationship between `pendingShipment` and `pendingShipmentDAO`? The new created `pendingShipment` is never used in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `self.pendingShipmentDAO` is `nil`, you still try to assign values to it in your `else` statement, instead of using `pendingShipment`, that you inserted into managed object context. When you perform fetch, you receive empty `pendingShipment` object.

So, you need to change code in the following way:

```
if (self.pendingShipmentDAO) {
    // Update existing device
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pointOfContact forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"empid"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"products"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"quantity"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"rate"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"amount"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"product_image"];
    [self.pendingShipmentDAO setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
} else {
    // Create a new device
    NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"shipmentno"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceNumber forKey:@"proforma_invoice_no"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:proformaInvoiceDate forKey:@"proforma_invoice_date"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceNo forKey:@"invoice_no"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:invoiceDate forKey:@"invoice_date"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:plannedShipmentDates forKey:@"planned_shipment_date"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:pointOfContact forKey:@"point_of_contact"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"empid"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"products"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"quantity"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"rate"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"amount"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:shipmentNumber forKey:@"product_image"];
    [pendingShipment setValue:pendingStatus forKey:@"status"];
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're inserting new entity in managed object context before this `if` statement. Looks like a bug:

```
NSManagedObject *pendingShipment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
// You never use this pendingShipment object!

if (self.pendingShipmentDAO) {
    // ...
```

Comment: thank you it works but it only prints the last value that is inserted. Is there anyways through which i can get all record in db in the form of arraylist?

Comment: `result` is an `NSArray`, but you are using only single object via `[result objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: @user31231234124, glad to help :)